# footer debajo de mis demás elementos

Tags: html, css

Estoy trabajando con mi *footer* de mi *app ecommerce* y lo que me sucede es que cuando estoy en el componente de mi página de productos, donde tengo veinte cards con ellos, los iconos `i` del *footer* quedan a la derecha y arriba de todo (lo que no es icono no), entonces le aplique un `margin top` y funciona, pero cuando voy a otra vista de mi app (por ejemplo: Nosotros), el *footer* queda muy debajo. Lo que estoy buscando hacer con CSS es que siempre quede debajo del elemento.

Muestro el codigo:

```css
.footer {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

.footer-redes ul {
  margin-left: 40%;
  margin-top: 155%;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
}

.footer-redes ul li {
  margin-left: 40px;
}

.footer p {
  font-size: 13px;
}

.footer-copy {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 40%;
}

.footer a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.footer a:hover {
  color: rgb(87, 86, 86);
}
```

```html
<div className="footer">
  <div className="footer-redes">
    <ul>
      <li><i className="bi bi-instagram"></i></li>
      <li><i className="bi bi-facebook"></i></li>
      <li><i className="bi bi-pinterest"></i></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div className="footer-copy">
    <p>Copyright Vanilla Deco&Hogar - 2023</p>
    <p>Todos los derechos reservados.</p>
  </div>

  <p>
    Defensa de las y los consumidores. Para reclamos
    <a href="https://autogestion.produccion.gob.ar/consumidores" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">ingrese aqui.</a>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: @Narciso-Aifuz Ojo que el código es de React (tiene _className_, no _class_). Si vas a agregar un snippet, tiene que ser incluyendo a React (y _tiene sus truquitos_ aquí, por cierto.)

Comment: has probado a agregarle estilos css a la clase footer. como position: fixed y bottom: 0?